# How to deploy your own Tangle currently?

Tags: documentation, private-network

I'm developing a project that runs upon a private Tangle, deployed locally on my PC. After some updates on the Wiki IOTA website (https://wiki.iota.org/), I can't find the relative documentation describing how to install and run a private Tangle anymore.

Where can I find it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We removed it as we are working on a new Projekt called [IOTA Sandbox](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota-sandbox)
which should help people develop their own INX plugins, test smart contracts and so on. With this new project we want to make clear that people should always use the public testnet first. If they need a private tangle for specific reasons we only support a development setup now with iota-sandbox.
So for now if there are good reasons for you to use a private tangle you can use the one in the [Hornet repo](https://github.com/iotaledger/hornet/tree/develop/private_tangle) until IOTA Sandbox is ready.

Answer (score 1):

We do not provide support for private Tangles. You can find a setup in [the Hornet repository](https://github.com/iotaledger/hornet/tree/develop/private_tangle), but it is intended for node and INX plugin development. For anything else we suggest using the provided [publicly available networks](https://wiki.iota.org/build/networks-endpoints/) for development.